# Accurately determine the real 'hardness' value of any given input instance for subset sum

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, np-hard

Assuming the 'hardness' of any possible input instance with $N$ elements (of any bit length) for the subset sum problem could be represented as $H \in \{0,0.000001,0.000002 \dots, 1 \}$, being ${0}$ those instances considered the most "easy" or "tractable" and ${1}$ those instances considered the "hardest" or "intractable" (with respect to all known methods to solve the problem...)

How interesting could be (academically or otherwise) to describe an algorithm able to determine the real value of ${H}$ in polynomial time for all known methods and possible input instances?

Comment: How would you define "hard" or "easy"? For any given instance $x$, the output is predetermined, and you could say that "$x$ is easy" since you can check if the input is exactly $x$, and if it is - just output the known answer for it.

Comment: In the context of subset sum problem a "hard [to solve]" instance is a well defined concept in the existing literature (likewise "easy [to solve]" instances). See [SETH-Based Lower Bounds for Subset Sum and Bicriteria Path](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/pdf/10.1137/1.9781611975482.3) for instance (Main Results section)

Comment: There's a field devoted to hardness and phase transitions that can perhaps point you in the right direction: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/37382/did-where-the-really-hard-problems-are-hold-up-what-are-current-ideas-on-the

Comment: @PålGD yes, I think you are spot on, I might need to post this question in TCS and get feedback there but first I am going to review the current state pulling from that thread information thank you!